# How to fix the following issue in React js

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, npx

What is the solution for the following error in React JS:

```
D:\\DDMD\\ReactProjects\>npx create-react-app pro01
npm ERR! code ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED
npm ERR! error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\\Users\\Admin\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache_logs\\2023-01-22T17_17_05_572Z-debug-0.log

=

versions
C:\\Users\\Admin\>npm -v
8\.19.3

C:\\Users\\Admin\>node -v
v18.13.0
```

Comment: first modify your question. Enter the question in a proper format. Your question is having hyperlink and it has been linked to the stackoverflow homepage, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

Some error occured in my current project,for fixing it please downgrade th node version 16+.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

your application or a module you’re using is attempting to use an algorithm or key size which is no longer allowed by default with OpenSSL 3.0. A command-line option, --openssl-legacy-provider

First try to update nodejs to the latest stable version. if that doesnt work try this workaround.

Open package.json and edit it

replace `"start": "react-scripts start" by "start": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start"`

replace `"build": "react-scripts build" by "build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build"`

Source - https://roytuts.com/how-to-fix-err_ossl_evp_unsupported-in-react-js-application/